# KeyboardAvoidingView isn't working on Android even when behavior is deleted

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I'm having an issue with KeyboardAvoidingView on android. It works just fine with iOS. My screen has a view components on the top half of the screen that may or may not be impacting it. I've tried deleting each of those components but KeyboardAvoidingView only works when I delete the the component that takes up 60% of the screen. This component is a YouTube player from 'react-native-youtube' which has a `flex: 1` style.

My code kind of looks like this..

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior="padding"
  keyboardVerticalOffset={200}
>
  <View style={styles.first}>
    <View style={styles.second}>
      <TouchableHighlight />
      <View style={styles.third}>
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.textInput}
          maxLength={80}
          autoGrow={true}
          maxHeight={130}
          multiline={true}
          editable={true}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          value={descriptionText}
          autoFocus={true}
          keyboardType={'default'}
          autoCorrect={false}
          placeholder={'Send a word'}
          underlineColorAndroid={white}
          selectionColor={purple}
          returnKeyType={'send'}
          onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
<KeyboardAvoidingView/>

first: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  position: 'relative',
  marginTop: 0,
},
second: {
  width: screenWidth,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  paddingTop: 5,
  paddingBottom: 9,
},
third: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
  paddingBottom: 5,
  paddingLeft: 10,
  paddingRight: 10,
  width: screenWidth - 102,
  minHeight: 36,
  alignItems: 'center',
},
textInput: {
  textAlign: 'left',
  fontSize: 14,
  fontWeight: '400',
  flex: 1,
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
}
```

Is there anything here that may impact `KeyboardAvoidingView`'s functionality? I've tried removing `behavior="padding"` already due to React Native docs that mention that it works better on android when that prop is removed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to add flex to all style might help, and maybe in the KeyboardAvoidingView also.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  keyboardVerticalOffset={0}
  behavior={'padding'}
>
```

Snack Expo: https://snack.expo.io/BJT-4Fphz

Comment: this didn't work either. tried adding `flex: 1` to each view around it. then took each one away one by one and it didn't work :( thx tho! any other recommendations would be awesome

Comment: @Dres you can play around in my snack link above.

Comment: thanks! soo much easier than reloading in the app i'm working on. i think the contents of the top half may be causing this expected behavior from happening. i'll keep plugging away on it!

Answer (score 0):

Working with the keyboard can be difficult.

However, Android (for once) does make it simpler.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';

componentDidMount() {
  if (isAndroid) {
    SoftInputMode.set(SoftInputMode.ADJUST_PAN);
  }
}
```

Comment: no go, i snagged SoftInputMode from https://github.com/MR03web/react-native-set-soft-input-mode, which has me editing build.gradle, settings.gradle, and mainapplication.java. i'm getting errors after doing all of that. thanks though!